# Group by two columns and output original data structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe table:

```
Test results | Make
     P       |  BMW
     F       |  VW
     F       |  VW
     P       |  VW
     P       |  VW
     P       |  VW
```

And I want to group by both make and test result to output a count something like this, including both original columns:

```
Test results | Make | count
     P       |  BMW |  1
     F       |  VW  |  2
     P       |  VW  |  3
```

I am currently doing:

```
pass_rates = df.groupby(['Test Results','Make']).size()
```

but it groups both make and test result in one column when I need it to stay in the original structure

Comment: call `reset_index`: `pass_rates = df.groupby(['Test Results','Make'']).size().reset_index()`

Comment: Ah, perfect. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with parameter `name`:

> **name** : object, default *None*
>
> The name of the column corresponding to the Series values

```
pass_rates = df.groupby(['Test Results','Make']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print pass_rates
  Test Results Make  count
0            F   VW      2
1            P  BMW      1
2            P   VW      3
```

If you want disable sorting, add parameter `sort=False` to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> **sort** : boolean, default *True*
>
> Sort group keys. Get better performance by turning this off. Note this does not influence the order of observations within each group. groupby preserves the order of rows within each group.

```
pass_rates = df.groupby(['Test Results','Make'], sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count')
print pass_rates
  Test Results Make  count
0            P  BMW      1
1            F   VW      2
2            P   VW      3
```